# Bteq if then condition

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, teradata, bteq

I have a Bteq script file which contain multiple queries like below:

```
Bteq

Quer1;
Quer2_a;
Quer2_b;
Quer3;
Quer4;
.if errorcode <> 0 then .goto end_err

.label end_ok
.quit 0

.label end_err
.quit 9

FIN
exit $?
```

Here I want to put a conditional expression if then
So if my condition is satisfied (current_date - tec_date > 1 year) then the quer2_a will be executed and the the quer2_b will be ignored then the script execute the other queries 3,4

if the condition is not satisfied the quer2_a will be ignored and the quer2_b,3,4 will be executed.

the queries 1,3 and 4 are independent of the condition.

Comment: You have to use ACTIVITYCOUNT here.  You would have a select that will return a # of rows, that goes into the activitycount.  Then you can branch based on that.

Comment: yes, this is what i'm trying to do now, have you any idea on how i can get the value of ACTIVITYCOUNT in my logs ?

Comment: BTEQ has very limited logging capabilities, to say the least.  Basically, you just get the commands you ran and their output, I don't think there is a way to show the value of a variable, or anything like that.

Comment: See the BTEQ documentation at docs.teradata.com site.  Note that current versions of BTEQ support multi-instruction IF / ELSEIF / ELSE / ENDIF blocks which can be nested, in addition to the old IF...THEN form.